# scipy stats beta returns negative values of alpha and beta when fit to a dataset

Tags: python, scipy, beta

When I fit `scipy.stats.beta` to a specific dataset given below, I get negative alpha and beta values which is unexpected because the values of alpha and beta must be > 0:

```
alpha: -6.83775430667913e-05 
beta: -8.398959053783684e-05
```

Here is the code:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
alp, bet, m, st  = stats.beta.fit(data)
print(alp, bet, m, st)

Result: -6.83775430667913e-05 -8.398959053783684e-05 -0.1 1.2
```

This might be a not yet handled bug in scipy.stats.beta or optimize.py or minpack.py I could not trace down. I get an array of inf as fsim. It might be the cause. Can you please help?

```
data= [0.686567,0.686567,0.731343,0.835821,0.776119,0.895522,0.850746,0.0149254,0.910448,0.955224,0.955224,0.507463,0.597015,0.626866,0.686567,0.701493,0.731343,0.761194,0.0149254,0.955224,0.970149,0.865672,0.0447761,0.0298507,0.0447761,0.298507,0.567164,0.61194,0.641791,0.0149254,0.850746,0.791045,0.701493,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.0447761,0.0298507,0.0447761,0.0149254,0.716418,0.701493,0.492537,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.0298507,0,0.641791,0.298507,0.0447761,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0298507,0.0447761,0.0149254,0.0298507,0,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0,0.0149254,0.0149254,0,0,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0,0.492537,0.447761,0.343284,0.253731,0,0,0.0149254,0.0298507,0,0.731343,0.656716,0.641791,0.597015,0.492537,0.447761,0.343284,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.0149254,0.880597,0.791045,0.880597,0.80597,0.731343,0.656716,0.641791,0.0298507,0.0149254,0.253731,0.61194,0.925373,0.880597,0.865672,0.761194,0.880597,0.791045,0.880597,0.0298507,0.343284,0.597015,0.716418,0.940299,0.865672,0.955224,0.895522,0.925373,0.880597,0.865672,0.0298507,0.641791,0.80597,0.80597,0.895522,0.835821,0.955224,0.820896,0.940299,0.865672,0.955224,0.0298507,0.880597,0.761194,0.925373,0.970149,0.865672,0.910448,0.850746,0.895522,0.820896,0.955224,0.0298507,0.865672,0.880597,0.880597,0.985075,0.925373,1,0.910448,0.955224,0.880597,0.925373,0.0149254,0.940299,0.80597,0.910448,0.955224,0.910448,0.985075,0.895522,0.985075,0.925373,0.985075,0.0149254,0.970149,0.850746,0.910448,0.955224,0.895522,0.940299,0.880597,0.940299,0.910448,1,0.0149254,0.895522,0.910448,0.940299,0.835821,0.850746,0.880597,0.910448,0.970149,0.895522,0.955224,0.0149254,0.970149,0.865672,0.940299]
```

I am getting these Warnings:

*.../scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:515: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  sk = 2*(b-a)*np.sqrt(a + b + 1) / (a + b + 2) / np.sqrt(a*b)*

*.../scipy/optimize/minpack.py:162: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last five Jacobian evaluations.*

*.../scipy/optimize/optimize.py:596: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  numpy.max(numpy.abs(fsim[0] - fsim[1:])) <= fatol)*